# Does Dell XPS 13 Ubuntu Edition come with drivers for fingerprint sensor and webcam drivers?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, dell, webcam, fingerprint-reader

I read the [article](https://ubuntu.com/blog/dell-xps-13-developer-edition-with-ubuntu-20-04-lts-pre-installed-is-now-available) about Dell XPS 13 will be available with Ubuntu 20.04 as default OS since 23rd June. Does it mean it has support for fingerprint, webcam and microphone? I have Dell XPS 7390 2-in-1 and I would really appreciate a resolution of this problem of missing drivers.

Thanks!

Comment: https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201910-27449 lists "Capture Integrated_Webcam_HD Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate" and "Fibocom 27c6:533c (27c6:533c) " (fingerprint reader), but I don't know how that's going to help your XPS 7390.

Answer (score 0):

The Dell XPS 13 2-in-1 7390 webcam is different hardware than on the developer edition xps 13 7390. Dell supports Ubuntu on the developer edition and the webcam works fine on that laptop.

Currently, the 2-in-1 webcam is NOT supported. See more information on the following links:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_2-in-1_(7390)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Dell/XPS/XPS-13-7390-2-in-1

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Dell_XPS_13_2-in-1_(7390)